# Getting names of composite setting values in a container

Tags: c#, uwp

My program has a feature to save composite settings using the methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)  What I want to do is to make it so I can create the name of the composite setting in the program using a textbox and then retrieve the setting by that name from a combobox.  Here's the code I'm using so far:

This is the class for the settings:

```
class settings
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    public void storeSetting(string key, string value)
    {
        localSettings.Values[key] = value;
    }

    public void storeSetting(string key, int value)
    {
        localSettings.Values[key] = value;
    }

    public void storeSetting(string key, ApplicationDataCompositeValue value)
    {
        localSettings.Values[key] = value;
    }

    public object loadSettings(string key)
    {
        if (localSettings.Values[key] != null)
        {
            return localSettings.Values[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void removeSetting(string key)
    {
        localSettings.Values.Remove(key);
    }
 }
```

Here is the code I use to save the settings:

```
ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
for (int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++)
{
    composite["sb" + i] = serial_buffer[i];
}

var storageHelper = new settings();
storageHelper.storeSetting(presetinput.Text, composite);
presets.Items.Add(presetinput.Text);
```

and here is the code I use to load the settings:

```
var storageHelper = new settings();
ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = (ApplicationDataCompositeValue)storageHelper.loadSettings(presets.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

This code works fine, however there is a problem in the way I'm populating the presets combobox.  I need a way to populate that combobox with the names of the settings that are already saved so I can re-populate it when I close and open the program and I'm not sure how to do it.  Is there a way to grab the names of the saved settings that have been created?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to grab the names of the saved settings that have been created?

We can use following code to retrieve the names of the saved settings.

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

var keys = localSettings.Values.Keys;

List<string> list = keys.ToList();
```

[ApplicationDataContainer.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer.values.aspx) property returns the settings in the settings container and its type is [**IPropertySet**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.collections.ipropertyset.aspx) which is a interface inherits `IObservableMap<String, Object>`, `IDictionary<String, Object>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>` interface. So we can use [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ebzfbyx(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get all keys. And then we can use [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get a list of the saved settings's name.